# Delete updater media file after update

Tags: install4j

We plan to use the "Update downloader with silent version check". In this aspect we would like to delete the downloaded mediafile which contains the update after the update has been successful.

The "Download File" action has a checkbox for "Delete downloaded file on exit". However, we assume that this is deleted when the User interrupts the updation. After a successful install, the .exe file is not deleted.

Is there any built in provision with install4j that supports this (or) writing an own Delete files action would be the way to go forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot delete the installer in the update downloader, because the update downloader will start the new installer and then exit. At the time when the update downloader exits, the installer is running and its executable cannot be deleted.

In the installer itself, you cannot delete the installer executable either. At the earliest, you can delete the installer executable in your own launcher when it is started the first time. You would have to program this kind of cleanup yourself.